# Assigning a function Value inside OnViewCreated Variable

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to get a JSON value from a function and trying to assign that value inside a onViewCreated method. The code is working fine but I am not sure how to assign the value inside a onViewCreated variable. Any help is appreciated.

**Main Activity**

```
var volleyRequest: RequestQueue?=null
val testlLink="https://www.abc.app"     
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
volleyRequest=Volley.newRequestQueue(this.context)
getTestData(testlLink)
val data=??????????????????
}
```

**Function**

```
fun getTestData(Url:String)
{

    val testRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url, Response.Listener {
        response: String ->
        try {
    Log.d("Response:",response)
        }catch (e: JSONException) { e.printStackTrace()}

    },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                error: VolleyError? ->
                try {
                    Log.d("Error:", error.toString())

                }catch (e: JSONException){e.printStackTrace()}
            })
    volleyRequest!!.add(testRequest)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not assign the result of the request to a variable because it is executed asynchronously. You have several options instead, like [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) or [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), but a simple solution could be to just pass callback functions that will be executed after the response arrives.

**Example**

```
lateinit var requestQueue: RequestQueue

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

    getTestData("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
        { body -> Log.d("Network", "Success: $body") },
        { error -> Log.d("Network", "Error", error) }
    )
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    requestQueue.cancelAll { true }
}

private fun getTestData(url: String, onSuccess: (String) -> Unit, onError: (Throwable) -> Unit) {
    val testRequest =  StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        Response.Listener { onSuccess(it) },
        Response.ErrorListener { onError(it)}
    )
    requestQueue.add(testRequest)
}
```

**Output**

```
D/Network: Success: {
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Omar Mainegra for your response. I am able to bring data back but no data visible on my activity and no error in the log cat as well.

Comment: Can you explain me two more questions. 1) How to get body value below getData function like var a=body  2) Now the JSON value I am getting is [{"school":"1","student":"20"}] and previously I am getting like  [{\"school\":\"1\",\"student\":\"20\"}]

Comment: @JoshvaJo The `onSuccess` could be whatever you want, is valid to say `{ body -> data = body }`, and about the JSON, it looks like is the same, just convert it to whatever you need

Comment: I am asking something like this one.    getTestData("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
        { body -> Log.d("Network", "Success: $body") },
        { error -> Log.d("Network", "Error", error) }
    ) var a=body

Comment: Nope, you can't do that, you need to do it in the callback, `getTestData("jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", { body -> data=body }, { error -> Log.d("Network", "Error", error) } )`

Comment: I am plotting chart and now I am getting null if I use the chart functions between body and error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185567/discussion-between-omar-mainegra-and-joshva-jo).

Comment: Its too weirdo for me. If I click the fragment then I am able to see the chart otherwise I am getting No Chart data available message.